# 2checkout unsuccess error,how to redirect in unsuccess case

Tags: php, 2checkout

I am using 2checkout.i have use the redirect url for success message but how can i get the error message and what are the error message that can be occur after completion of all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [2Checkout's hosted standard or inline checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/), and authorization failure will result in the failure message being displayed to the buyer so that they can correct the details and resubmit. A passback will only be sent to your approved URL when the authorization is successful.

If you are using the [2Checkout Payment API](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/), the [error JSON response](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/create-sale) will be returned to your server.

**PHP Example:**

```
Twocheckout::privateKey('BE632CB0-BB29-11E3-AFB6-D99C28100996');
Twocheckout::sellerId('901248204');
// Twocheckout::sandbox(true);  #Uncomment to use Sandbox

try {
    $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
        "merchantOrderId" => "123",
        "token" => 'Y2U2OTdlZjMtOGQzMi00MDdkLWJjNGQtMGJhN2IyOTdlN2Ni',
        "currency" => 'USD',
        "total" => '10.00',
        "billingAddr" => array(
            "name" => 'Testing Tester',
            "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
            "city" => 'Columbus',
            "state" => 'OH',
            "zipCode" => '43123',
            "country" => 'USA',
            "email" => 'testingtester@2co.com',
            "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
        ),
        "shippingAddr" => array(
            "name" => 'Testing Tester',
            "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
            "city" => 'Columbus',
            "state" => 'OH',
            "zipCode" => '43123',
            "country" => 'USA',
            "email" => 'testingtester@2co.com',
            "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
        )
    ), 'array');
    if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
        echo "Thanks for your Order!";
    }
} catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Please reach out to 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2co.com if you would like further assistance with your sandbox testing.